# Dynamically change min, max date on datetime change event in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I'm using an existing directive to select start date and end date.

Requirement:

- End Date always should be equal or greater than Start Date.
- User may select start date as a `future day` or `old day`. min date of the End Date time picker should be set disabled based on start date selection.

Can anyone suggest me, how to set min date for end date dynamically based on start date?

start Date:

```
<input singledatepicker class="form-control" selected-date="startDateTime" placeholder="Date" format="DD/MM/YYYY" required readonly style="background:white;" max-date={{pastDate}}>
```

End Date:

```
<input singledatepicker class="form-control" selected-date="endDateTime" placeholder="Date" format="DD/MM/YYYY" required readonly style="background:white;" min-date={{IwantToSetThisValue}}>
```

Comment: Which library/existing directive are you using? Does this provide you with some bindings to set `min` and `max` dates on the datepicker?

Comment: @Kiran using `daterangepicker`

Comment: Doesn't this library already provide you with a range date picker or do you not want to use it? Can you point me to the exact library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of daterangepicker, we can see that, there are options available to set

```
> minDate: (Date or string) The earliest date a user may select.
> maxDate: (Date or string) The latest date a user may select
```

but these values need to set while initializing the daterangepicker object. and u need to update this min date, according to the start date.

As this daterangepicker library not providing any methods to update the option on runtime, one quick solution is to reinitialize the 'end date picker' option with value of 'start date picker'.

You watch the start date model value and reinitilize the end date picker on the value change, something like this:

```
    $scope.$watch('startDateTime', function (startDateValue) {
        if (startDateValue) {
            $('#endDateTime').daterangepicker({
                minDate: startDateValue // Do corrections according to the requirements
            });
       }
    });
```

Note: I'm not sure what your `singledatepicker` directive is doing, This is just a workaround, not the perfect way, But hope you got the idea.